# How to use same Redis instance as both message broker and in-memory database?

Tags: node.js, redis, message-queue

I have chosen `Redis` as *in-memory database* for my IOT application. The application also needs to subscribe to queue messages received from sensor devices. These messages needs to be stored in *in-memory database* for streaming-analytics. Is it proper approach to use same instance of `Redis` as `in-memory database` and also `message broker`?

Comment: I think you can do so **BUT** you need to find a way that the subscriber is not blocked to recieving messages using a redis connection. In `spring-data-redis` you can define a listener and assigned it to a connection, so the listener handles messages asynchronously (once a message is published)  [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-pub-sub) is an example . So if you find something like that to be used in your environemnet you will be able to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is possible, but will require two separate connections to different databases on the same instance.

Redis allows for up to 16 separate databases per Redis instance (server, essentially). Each one is assigned a number between `0` and `15`. By default, when you start Redis, database `0` is selected. You can switch between them using the [`SELECT`](http://redis.io/commands/select) command:

```
SELECT 1
```

You can specify which database to open using the redis-cli by using the `-n` argument.

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 6390 -n 1
```

You can specify which database in your connection string by appending `/1` (or whatever database number you wish to target).

```
redis.connect('localhost/1');
```

If your server is remote, simply replace `localhost/0` with your remote host URL and add a `/1` (or whatever database number you wish to target) on the end.

Comment: by the way, default database number is: 16 but you can change the configuration to be more than 16.

Answer (score 1):

According to Redis [SUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/subscribe) command

> Once the client enters the subscribed state it is not supposed to
>   issue any other commands, except for additional SUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE,
>   UNSUBSCRIBE and PUNSUBSCRIBE commands.

so, you can't use same `connection instance` for `in-memory database` and `message broker` in same time.

Comment: You can't use the same _connection_ for both message broker (pub/sub, really) and in-memory database, but you can use the same Redis server for both just fine.